Is there to fetch existing pool list from raydium in devnet
I am testing swap feature for coins in Devnet. But I don't want to create a new market/pool by myself. I am wondering whether I can fetch existing pool list in Devnet and swap from there?

My best guess is pulling the Raydium UI locally, switching the constants to Devnet and getting the information from there.
Going to try it out now.
Here is the Raydium UI repo:
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-ui.git
Here is the Reddit post from where I got the idea:
https://www.reddit.com/r/solana/comments/1aidcsc/how_to_use_raydium_for_devnet/
